# Haskell - Restrict data parameters

Tags: haskell, types, restriction, type-parameter, custom-data-type

I am trying to create the following datatypes:

```
data ExprValues = ExprNum Int |
                  ExprIdent String |
                  ExprChar Char |
                  ExprString String
                  deriving(Eq, Show, Read)

data ExprOverall = ExprFunCall ExprValues  --correct this to use ExprIdent solely
                   deriving(Eq, Show, Read)
```

However, as it is indicated in the comment, I want that **ExprValues** next to the **ExprFuncall** to accept **ExprIdent String** only, not the other ExprValues. How am I able to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, if you want to allow only the constructor, why not just “inline” it – store a `String` right in `ExprOverall` and be done?

But more generally, this sort of restriction can be implemented with GADTs. Often, especially for such AST-like types, you want to express the overall type the expression stands for. There, `ExprIdent` might be polymorphic while the others are concrete:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data ExprValues a where
  ExprNum :: Int -> ExprValues Int
  ExprIdent :: String -> ExprValues a
  ExprChar :: Char -> ExprValues Char
  ExprString :: String -> ExprValues String
```

Then, for use in `ExprOverall` you select a unique tag-type that is only applicable to the `ExprIdent` constructor (because that allows any type variable `a`, whereas the others are specific to a concrete type).

```
data FreeIdentifier

data ExprOverall = ExprFunCall (ExprValues FreeIdentifier)
```

Comment: Yes, I exactly need this for producing AST, so I cannot go the easy way, and thank you so much for your help!